# Postgres ERROR: Deleting operation must have an username set for this operation

Tags: postgresql

I am a beginner in using PostgreSQL. I am trying to delete a row from a Postgres table but after running the query, I receive the following message:

> ERROR:  Deleting operation must have an username set for this operation
> HINT:  Use set_config('myvars.app_user' for this operation

I do not fully understand how I should write the query in order to delete the desired row.

Any hints on how can I achieve this?

I wrote the following query:

```
DELETE
FROM table
WERE id = id_number
```

After that, I received the above error message.

I understand that I must state a username (Admin most probably since I have these privileges) but I don't fully understand how should I write the query for the trigger function to accept the delete statement.

I have read the trig_fct code but to no end.

Comment: That's not a Postgres error message. You have most probably a trigger that checks some custom setting. Did you try the hint to run `set_config()` to provide the needed value.

Comment: To be clear this is coming from Postgres. It just not a built in message from the server code itself, it is coming from a user built error reply. My guess from `trig_fct code`. Is it possible to add that code to the question?